# how to remove the new line and tab in powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

below is my powershell code, to remove all the newlines and tabs of 'data6.xml', but it didn't work at all!

```
function Replace-String($find, $replace)
{
   (Get-Content C:/Temp/data6.xml) | 
   Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $find, $replace} | 
   Set-Content C:/Temp/data6.xml    
}

# to remove the [CDATA] tag
Replace-String "\<!\[CDATA\[" "" 
Replace-String "\]\]\>"  ""
Replace-String "\n"  ""
Replace-String "`n"  ""
Replace-String "`t"  ""
Replace-String "\n"  ""
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/325953/

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Get-Content` gives you an array of lines, each of which, naturally, has no line breaks in it.

So I guess what you want is something like the following:

```
-join ((Get-Content data6.xml) -replace '<!\[CDATA\[|]]|(?<=>)\s+(?=<)') | Set-Content data6.xml
```

Comment: cool!, but one last problem: how to remove the spaces between tags? I found there are four spaces between each two

Comment: See edited code. This might mangle content, though. But then again, so do the other replacements.