# Powershell Regex acting per-line rather than on entire string

Tags: regex, powershell

Given foo.txt

```
this is a file
it has some text
the text has three lines
```

The following regex replacement

```
(get-content -raw foo.txt) -replace ".*", "hello" | write-output
```

produces the output

```
hellohello
hellohello
hellohello
```

rather than the desired

```
hello
```

My understanding was that `get-content` returns the content as an array of strings, one per line. The `-raw` flag replaces this behavior with returning the contents as a single string. As far as I know, `".*"` should match the entire string, but instead it matches twice on each line.

Please advise.

Comment: try `(get-content -raw foo.txt) -replace ".+", "hello" | write-output`

Comment: That produces 'hello\nhello\nhello\n'. (Can't do multiline comments, but I hope you get the drift.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inline `(?s)` (*dotall*) modifier which forces `.` to span across newlines.

```
(Get-Content .\foo.txt -Raw) -replace "(?s).+", "hello"
```

**Example:**

```
PS> $data = Get-Content .\foo.txt -Raw
PS> $data
this is a file
it has some text
the text has three lines
PS> $data -replace "(?s).+", "hello"
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it other than to say that `.` appears not to be matching newline characters so you get one match for each complete line then one match for the zero characters at the end of each line.

This also explains the `.+` behavior of `hello` once per-line.

You can "fix" this by using a better pattern that does match the newline characters.

```
(Get-Content -raw .\foo.txt) -replace "(.|\r|\n)+", "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674250/1252649,

> The trick around DotAll mode is to use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`. This character class matches any character ...

Of course, this raises the question as to what exactly `.` is supposed to match other than 'any character'.