# Get UnxUtils tr.exe for Windows work like the Unix tr with character escaping

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, unix, tr

From another cross-platform program I would like to use the [UnxUtils](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) tr.exe program exactly as under Unix but I can't manage to get it to work, the issue being the escaping. Here's an example.

Create a file blah.txt with content

```
%^&<>|'`,;=()!\"\\[].*?
```

Then

```
type blah.txt | tr.exe "*" "X"
```

> tr.exe: extra operand `blah.txt' Try `tr.exe --help' for more
>   information.

The problem is that Windows expands * to the files in the directory. But under Unix this is no problem. No matter what I tried, I can't escape the * properly under Windows. Similarly with the quotation mark ". Even if I can figure out how to rewrite the escaping properly, it will be a mess to apply this correction to a set of characters.

I managed to get sed.exe from the UnxTools to work consistently because here I can use program files with the -f option so that I don't need to escape things.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ironically, this post required some escaping as well

Comment: Haha, very good. Thanks!

Comment: (By the way: same issue with the GnuWin32 tr.exe but \" works here correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some easy portable ways to deal with the file globbing when using `*` (by the way, as MSalters points it is not a windows feature)

```
type blah.txt | tr.exe \52 X
type blah.txt | tr.exe [=*=] X
```

Comment: Wow, this works! Thanks so much. I can't upvote yet unfortunately because not enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Windows (CMD.EXE) does not expand `*`. Ever. That's why escaping won't fix it. That's how `dir /s *.txt` can find text files in subdirectories. It wouldn't work if `*.txt` was expanded in the directory where you currently are.

That's why Windows tools need to handle `*`. Apparently `tr.exe` gets it wrong.

Comment: Got it. Any alternative tool with a similar behavior that reads a program file like sed? I'm dealing with newlines etc which is horrendous in sed, that's why I wanted to go for tr.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291986/what-is-the-tr-command-in-windows

Comment: Okay, doesn't work with character classes etc. though I think.