# Powershell works differently for two similar operation

Tags: powershell

With reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326082/5023367), I tried to do it with two different approaches and apparently PowerShell is responding differently but it should be same I think. Can anyone explain why it is different?

```
PS C:\> $x = "Hello
World"

PS C:\> $x
Hello
World

PS C:\> $x.Contains('`n')
False

PS C:\> $x.Contains("`n")
True

PS C:\> $x -Contains "`n"
False

PS C:\> $x -Contains '`n'
False
```

Comment: `-contains` is for arrays. Try `-like`

Comment: Backquote ` is an escape character. You have to tell powershell not to treat it as one.

Comment: @RohinSidharth but this is exactly what Adeel wants to do. (S)he wants to search for `\`n`, not for `\`\`n`

Comment: Have a look at the [`about_Quoting_Rules` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quoted strings are not evaluated, so backtick is not being treated as escape character and the string is not being resolved as newline.

`-contains` is a containment comparison operator and only works on collections, just like `-in`.

So everything's fine :).